# Split string into 2 elements before the last full stop in a string and removing punctuation characters from the second element in R?

Tags: r, regex, string

I am trying to split a string:

`What.I.Am.Testing.TRUE_` into 2 separate elements as `What.I.Am.Testing` and `TRUE`

I plan on splitting the two elements apart by splitting before the 4th punctuation character i.e. the full stop, to get the strings

`What.I.Am.Testing` and `.TRUE_`

I then need a way to remove the `.` and the `_` on the second (last) split string. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `sub` here:

```
x <- "What.I.Am.Testing.TRUE_"
p1 <- sub("\\.[^.]+$", "", x)
p2 <- sub("^.*\\.([^_]+)_$", "\\1", x)
p1
p2

[1] "What.I.Am.Testing"
[1] "TRUE"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_match` and extract both the groups in one-call

```
x <- c("What.I.Am.Testing.TRUE_", "What.I.Am.Testing.FALSE_")
stringr::str_match(x, "(.*)\\.(\\w+)_")[, 2:3]

#      [,1]                [,2]   
#[1,] "What.I.Am.Testing" "TRUE" 
#[2,] "What.I.Am.Testing" "FALSE"
```

You get an output as matrix where 1st column is output from 1st group and 2nd output from the  second group.